# Lat/Long to XY conversion with Geometry Service

Tags: arcgis-server, coordinate-system, arcgis-silverlight-api

I am attempting to make a simple map that will allow users to see a truck's GPS location on top of a tiled map service. I am having difficulty getting the graphic symbol to overlap my tiled service because the spatial systems do not match.

Is there a good example or could someone help me conversion through a geometry service? Is a geometry service even the correct method to use for plotting my graphics?

Here is my code so far.

Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TruckGPS_Test.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400"
    xmlns:esri="http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/client/2009"
             xmlns:esriSymbols="clr-namespace:ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols;assembly=ESRI.ArcGIS.Client">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">


        <Grid.Resources>
             <esri:SimpleMarkerSymbol x:Key="RedMarkerSymbol" Color="Red" Size="12" Style="Circle" />
            <esri:SimpleMarkerSymbol x:Key="YellowMarkerSymbol" Color="Yellow" Size="25" Style="Circle" />
            <esriSymbols:PictureMarkerSymbol x:Name="TRUCK" Source="images/bucket-truck-box.png" />
        </Grid.Resources>


        <esri:Map x:Name="MyMap" WrapAround="True" Margin="0,0,-325,-506" MouseMove="MyMap_MouseMove">
            <!--<esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="MyLayer"
                Url="http://gisaprd/ArcGIS/rest/services/BaseMap_ArcReader_Cached/MapServer" />-->
            <!--<esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="MyLayer"
                Url="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer" />-->
            <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="Aerials" Url="http://gisaprd/ArcGIS/rest/services/AerialCoordinateTest/MapServer" Visible="False"  />
            <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer Url="http://gisaprd/ArcGIS/rest/services/BaseMapCool__WebViewer/MapServer" />

            <esri:GraphicsLayer ID="TruckGPS" >

                <esri:GraphicsLayer.MapTip>
                    <Grid Background="#FFD65555" >
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FFFF0000" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding [USER_NAME]}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding [SYSTIME]}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </esri:GraphicsLayer.MapTip>
            </esri:GraphicsLayer>

        </esri:Map>

        <Grid MinWidth="300" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,15,15,0" >
            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                <TextBlock x:Name="ScreenCoordsTextBlock" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Screen Coords: "
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="MapCoordsTextBlock" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Map Coords: " 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Bing;


namespace TruckGPS_Test
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
             //AddMarkerGraphics();

            QueryTask queryTaskTruckGPS = new QueryTask("http://gisaprd/ArcGIS/rest/services/TruckGPS/MapServer/8");
            queryTaskTruckGPS.ExecuteCompleted += QueryTask_ExecuteCompletedTruckGPS;
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Query queryTruckGPS = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Query();
            queryTruckGPS.OutFields.Add("*");
            queryTruckGPS.ReturnGeometry = false;
            queryTruckGPS.Where = "1=1";
            queryTaskTruckGPS.ExecuteAsync(queryTruckGPS, "initial");

            //This timer updates the outage feature count after a 30 second wait
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer myDispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            myDispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10, 0);
            myDispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Each_Tick);
            myDispatcherTimer.Start();

        }

        public void Each_Tick(object o, EventArgs sender)
        {
            QueryTask queryTaskTruckGPS = new QueryTask("http://gisaprd/ArcGIS/rest/services/TruckGPS/MapServer/8");
            queryTaskTruckGPS.ExecuteCompleted += QueryTask_ExecuteCompletedTruckGPS;
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Query queryTruckGPS = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Query();
            queryTruckGPS.OutFields.Add("*");
            queryTruckGPS.ReturnGeometry = false;
            queryTruckGPS.Where = "1=1";
            queryTaskTruckGPS.ExecuteAsync(queryTruckGPS, "initial");

        }

        private void QueryTask_ExecuteCompletedTruckGPS(object sender, ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.QueryEventArgs args)
        {
            //If Counter isn't working check the web service, make sure the table is added to the map service

            FeatureSet featureSet = args.FeatureSet;
            GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = MyMap.Layers["TruckGPS"] as GraphicsLayer;
            graphicsLayer.ClearGraphics();
            if (featureSet != null && featureSet.Features.Count > 0)
            {

                ////Check the system time and subtract the time amount wanted from the last gps systime read for movement or idle truck
                //System.DateTime dTime = DateTime.Now;
                //// tSpan is 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, and 0 seconds.
                //System.TimeSpan tSpan = new System.TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0);
                //System.DateTime result = dTime - tSpan;


                foreach (ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic feature in featureSet.Features)
                {

                    if ((feature.Attributes["LONGITUDE"] != null) && (feature.Attributes["LATITUDE"] != null) ) 
                        //&& (feature.Attributes["S"])
                    {

                        var Machine_Name = feature.Attributes["MACHINE_NAME"].ToString();
                        var User_Name = feature.Attributes["USER_NAME"].ToString();
                        double x = Convert.ToDouble(feature.Attributes["LONGITUDE"]);
                        double y =Convert.ToDouble(feature.Attributes["LATITUDE"]);

                        feature.Geometry = new MapPoint(x, y);
                        //if (User_Name == "CU656")
                        //{
                            feature.Symbol = LayoutRoot.Resources["TRUCK"] as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.Symbol;
                            graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(feature);
                        //}
                        //else
                        //{
                        //    feature.Symbol = LayoutRoot.Resources["RedMarkerSymbol"] as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.Symbol;
                        //    graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(feature);
                        //}
                    }
                }
                { (MyMap.Layers["TruckGPS"] as GraphicsLayer).Refresh(); };
            }
            else
            {
                graphicsLayer.ClearGraphics();
                //MessageBox.Show("No features returned from query");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: when you are using a Query Task, you can request the output in your required projection itself. If you do this, you don't have to project the Geometry either by using the inbuilt classes in the API, or using a Geometry service. This would be the best way of solving this issue.

Comment: That sounds great Devdatta Tengshe! Is there any chance you would have an example of this or a link to an example so I can explore the topic more thoroughly?

Comment: I'm in the phone right now, so can't refer to the docs. But you should have a look at the outputspatialReference parameters of the query class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coordinate conversion - Lat Long to State Plane, ArcServer-Silverlight](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78773/coordinate-conversion-lat-long-to-state-plane-arcserver-silverlight)

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to your [other very similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78773/coordinate-conversion-lat-long-to-state-plane-arcserver-silverlight) for example code using the Silverlight API's GeometryService Project operation.